# Why can't other people in same network view wordpress built in localhost?

Tags: localhost

I am currently developing my own  wordpress website, and I am hosting it locally using XAMPP using bitnami.

So, my friend on same network try to open url **http://172.25.60.107/wordpress/lm_ppt/** but it say site can’t be reached.

Any idea?

Comment: this goes into network engineering and firewalls, way beyond anything that is specific to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

To share the local sites you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or use [laragon](https://laragon.org/) which comes with website sharing option.
or follow the steps 
https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/05/accessing-your-local-web-server-from-a-mobile-device-using-xampp/

Comment: xammp is just a packaging of LAMP tools for windows, there is no magic about it, and the tools operate exactly the same as if they were in a "proper" hosting enviroment.

Comment: agree.. so whats the reason of downvoting my answer i have just given him the option to share his local sites to other people?

Comment: it is incorrect, you can access xamp from anywhere if your network is set correctly

Comment: on windows you most likely need to first disable the firewall on port 80, in big organization there might be other firewalls in the way

Comment: is it? i dint know that.. thanks for clearing my doubt..

Comment: removed the downvote, but you are unlikely to be able to install and properly configure such tools in a secure IT enviroment. They basically violate core principals of security ;)

Comment: i am in office using laragon and sharing local web copies via ngrok ;) ... with the team of 10

Comment: If you are using ngrok or laragon for a local dev environment to be shared in office, there's nothing wrong with this answer. These tools should not be used for a production environment. So you are both not wrong, you are just arguing about different scenarios and getting your wires crossed over.

Comment: there is no argument.. it's just a healthy discussion ... to gain some knowledge :)